# Como hago que, al soltar un botón en otro sitio, haga de igual el evento?

Tags: java, netbeans, mouselistener

Tengo un JLabel al cual le asigne un `MouseEvent`, el problema es que si yo presiono el boton y lo suelto en otro sitio diferente a donde esta el boton, no pasa nada, no se reproduce el evento que le tengo asignado, como podria solucionarlo?

Este es el array en el cual tengo el problema:

```
public void Botones(){
    for(int i = 0, y = 0; i < 3; i++, y += 79){
        for(int j = 0, x = 0; j < 3; j++, x += 79){
            boton[i][j] = new JLabel();
            boton[i][j].setBounds(x,y,72,72);
            boton[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
            boton[i][j].setFont(new Font("Verdana",0,44));
            boton[i][j].setBackground(new Color(20, 189, 172));
            boton[i][j].setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
            boton[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            boton[i][j].setCursor(new Cursor(HAND_CURSOR));
            boton[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                            if(e.getSource() == boton[i][j]){
                                if(boton[i][j].getText().equals("")){
                                    if(Turno == "X"){
                                        boton[i][j].setForeground(new Color(84, 84, 84));
                                        boton[i][j].setText(Turno);
                                        Turno = "O";
                                    } else {
                                        boton[i][j].setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
                                        boton[i][j].setText(Turno);
                                        Turno = "X";
                                    }
                                }       
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                }
            });
            PanelLineas.add(boton[i][j]);
      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si te fijas en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) te indican exactamente el por qué: `mouseClicked` se dispara solo cuando se cumplen `mousePressed` y `mouseReleased` en el mismo botón. Si quieres que se disparen al *soltar* el botón, simplemente mueve tu código a `mouseReleased`!

Comment: Depronto a ti te parecera obvio ya que no eres novato, ni sabia que era una documentacion, pero siempre pregunto algo, y todos me tratan mal :(

Comment: Todos somos novatos en algún momento. Yo mismo sigo sin tener toda la experiencia que me gustaría... y de todos modos, los programadores nunca dejamos de aprender, puesto que la tecnología evoluciona y cambia *muy* rápido. No te sientas mal por preguntar, es la manera de aprender! Pero siempre es mejor antes de preguntar *investigar* y sobre todo, *toquetear*. Se aprende mucho *rompiendo y arreglando* el código uno mismo. Cuando te dan la respuesta es más fácil que te olvides que si lo descubres tú mismo tras un rato intentándolo.

Comment: Pues tomare en cuenta eso y antes de preguntar mirare la documentación haber que me encuentro, si no encuentro lo buscado preguntare acá, gracias!